# scheduling process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am working with a scheduling process in `node.js`

for that i write a sample `script.js` file and it is executed correctly with no issues

```
 // it executes every sunday at 14:29PM
        var rule = {hour: 14, minute: 29, dayOfWeek: 0};
        schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
          console.log("Execute me at sunday .............")
        });
```

The above code will only execute at sunday 14:29PM.

But while using the above same code as follows it executes every time

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var http = require('http');



 var jobScedule = function (time, jobid) { 
        schedule.scheduleJob(time, function () {
console.log("execute me at sunday") // it executes every time when i called this function
            console.log(time);
        });
    }
exports.jobScedule = jobScedule;
```

i calls in another file

```
 var objSchedule = require('./script.js');
 var rule = {hour: 23, minute: 60, dayOfWeek: 0};
 objSchedule.jobScedule(rule, jobid);
```

Comment: I've set your code up exactly as you've got it and the scheduling works fine for me -- obviously I had to define a `jobid`, but apart from that it all works. Perhaps you need to upgrade your `node-schedule` module? I'm running node 0.10.18, and node-schedule 0.1.13 on Mac OSX.

Comment: you are telling the second code works fine for you?

Comment: Yep, if I run your exact code I just get a prompt obviously waiting for Sunday, if I shift the rule to be within a minute of running the code it executes once as expected, at the right time.

Comment: but in my case while puting schedulejob inside a function it executes every time with out considering the time i have set

Comment: If you update your question with the exact code you are running i.e. the content of the entire raw file(s), perhaps there might be something odd that the Stack Overflow community can spot. If you've pretty much already done that above though, I would look into upgrading your software versions as something odd is going on.

Comment: Just in case it's useful here is the exact code that I've tried locally ~ https://gist.github.com/codelamp/7333666